# using Process.Start in an IIS Website

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, batch-file, iis-7, permissions

I have created an ASP.NET website using VB.NET. The functionality of the website generates a .bat file and saves it in a location - it then uses `Process.Start(filelocation)` to run the bat file.

This works fine when in debug mode on my PC - but when I have uploaded the website on to an IIS 7 server, it creates the file (proving that it has access to the area), but seemingly cannot run it?

I am assuming there is a permission issue here - Any ideas what I am missing?

Thanks
Guy

Answer (score 1):

Every webapp in IIS run under a specific user. Check if that user has privileges to run applications, in particular the *.bat (in your output directory) and related *.exe files.
If you do not use impersonation, you can set the user at App pool level.
My suggestion is to create a dedicated Windows user with the right permissions and run the app pool under that user. The app pool should contains only your web application.